# How to edit Gatsby GraphQL data without modifying the original

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql

I'm building a site with Gatsby and fetching data from WordPress.

I can't stand the `Node` hell so I wanted to sanitize the data.
The problem occurs when revisiting the page again (Without browser refresh) it now throws an error that `Node` is undefined.

Honestly, the Gatsby docs are a mess so I still have no clue how the graphql part works.

Query in the `index` file:

```js
export const query = graphql`
    query {
        allWpMasina(limit: 6) {
            nodes {
                id
                atrumkarbas {
                    nodes {
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

All cars have only one "atrumkarbas" so I just wanted to assign the name for it without writing `atrumkarbas.node[0].name` everytime I want to access it.

So in the index page I added the following:

```
const IndexPage = ({ data: { allWpMasina } }) => {
    let cars = allWpMasina.nodes;
    cars.forEach((car) => {
        car.atrumkarbas = car.atrumkarbas.nodes[0].name;
```

As you can see, it got rid of the `.nodes[0].name` and it all works perfectly.
But when I revisit the page:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

I tried adding `let cars = allWpMasina.nodes.map()` so it copies it everytime without modifying the `data.allWpMasina` but somehow it still caches them both and messes up the re-visit.

Console logging before the changes outputs the already formatted result! If I remove the `forEach` it goes back to node node node, but when I add it back on, the `allWpMasina` is now the same as `cars` before the `forEach` is even executed!

How does Gatsby handle the Graphql data? How can I copy and modify it without affecting the original data?

Comment: fix it at source of problem ... just define a field (one value) of CPT, not a relation (an array)

Comment: @xadm But we need to pre-define the options and making it non-relational would then make it unique every time. I also use ACF so maybe it's just better to query everything through it? Even the taxonomies?

Comment: many [posts/cpts] to one [value] instead of many [posts/cpts] to many [values] - still a relation, a "choose one" option